# Cannot select element(class) using Selenium webdriver Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, screenshot

It works on unique elements, I tried using find_elements and then indexing the list to get the object, it didn't work.

```
driver =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(href)
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.add_stat_table")
print(element)
location = element[1].location
print(location)
size = element[1].size
print(size)
driver.save_screenshot("path/image.png")
x = location['x']
y = location['y']
width = location['x'] + size['width']
height = location['y'] + size['height']
print(size['width'], size['height'])
im = Image.open("path/image.png")
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))
im.save("path/image.png")

driver.quit()
```

HTML Snippet
[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.